# String as delimiter for `paste` command

Tags: shell, unix, paste

I have three files with the following contents:

**one.txt**

```
a
b
c
```

**two.txt**

```
1
2
3
```

**three.txt**

```
Some text with all kinds of characters (but no single quote).
More text, also with "all kinds of characters" (and no single quote either).
Same as before.
```

I want to combine the three files into:

```
'a', '1', 'Some text with all kinds of characters (but no single quote).'
'b', '2', 'More text, also with "all kinds of characters" (and no single quote either).'
'c', '3', 'Same as before.'
```

that is, I want the string `', '` (i.e. single quote, comma, space, single quote) as delimiter between the three files, and – if you want to try your hand at an advanced answer – a `'` a the beginning and end of each new line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `paste` with `awk`:

```
paste one.txt two.txt three.txt | awk -F '\t' -v SQ="'" -v OFS=', ' '{
     for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) printf "%s%s%s%s", SQ, $i, SQ, (i<NF)?OFS:ORS}'
'a', '1', 'Some text with all kinds of characters (but not single quote).'
'b', '2', 'More text, also with "all kinds of characters" (and no single quote either).'
'c', '3', 'Same as before.'
```

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/115756/77458 for a beautiful usage without writing any code !